# How to refactor a single row insert query into multiple rows insert query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL insert query that currently inserts a single row's parameter values for a given item id. I need to refactor it so that it inserts multiple rows of a join table, one for each parameter where parameter name and value and inserted for each row instead of a single row.

The current query has complex subqueries that I am omitting here in this simplified example below. My goal is to be able to refactor the top portion and leave the subqueries as they are so if it means wrapping a new top level around all of it that is ok.

```
INSERT INTO parameters (
    item_id
    category, 
    color, 
    size, 
    weight, 
    pressure,
    price) 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            item_id
            c_from_box AS category_id,
            c_from_pack AS color, 
            s_from_ship AS size, 
            w_from_ship AS weight, 
            p_from_box AS pressure,
            p_from_acc AS price
        FROM
            FROM_PART_NUMBER_SUBQUERY
        WHERE
            WHERE_LOGIC_FOR_SUBQUERY
        ) 
    WHERE 
        SOME_OTHER_WHERE_LOGIC
)
```

I need to refactor it so instead of the parameters table having a column for parameter, its a column for the parameter id. So instead of this:

```
item_id
    category, 
    color, 
    size, 
    weight, 
    pressure,
    price
```

it is

```
item_id
    parameter_id, value
```

where the parameter_ids are the possibilities of the corresponding parameter names (name and id from another table):

```
    category, // parameter_id: 1
    color,    // parameter_id: 2
    size,     // parameter_id: 3
    weight,   // parameter_id: 4
    pressure, // parameter_id: 5
    price     // parameter_id: 6
```

I essentially want to transpose the insertion of multiple columns to be multiple rows but it needs to be a single overall top level query execution even if nested into multiple subqueries. What are my options for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the insert you have, and then perform a second insert that melts the table into the format you want.  Specifically:

```
insert into final (item_id, parameter_id, value)
(
select item_id, 1, category from parameters
union all
select item_id, 2, color from parameters
union all
...
)
```

Package both steps into a single transaction.

Comment: Hmm - ok so what is "final" supposed to be? A new table? The goal was to have a single end resulting table the same as before but just with a different schema. Are you suggesting two tables are needed? Would an intermediate table be a temporary table then?

Comment: Is the only way to do this to pull from an intermediate table that the first insert injects its results into? Or could the same approach here identified above be done by pulling from an alias to the current insert that is treated as select subquery vs an insert?

Comment: You mentioned the need to refactor into a table with three columns, "final" is that table.

Comment: I don't completely understand your second question.  I think you're asking if the "parameters" in my answer can be a subselect, to which the answer is yes, but it probably won't be very efficient.